# Kali linux to be installed as a boot option

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, partitioning

I only have the current Ubuntu 14 on my harddrive. How do I partition my hard drive so I can have a second OS such as kali linux, thus creating a dual boot-up option when i power up?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! You might want to search for dual-boot questions separately from partitioning questions. I know there are a great many answers here on both topics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gparted on a livecd to resize the main partition to a size that leaves enough free space for what you want on the kali installation, create an ext4 partition in the free space, and simply install. Grub will add all available bootable OSs to the menu when you install it as it just runs a normal "update-grub (disk)" command during installation

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party software such as GParted.
While partition the disk make sure  you have to make three partitions

1. 1.swap area (4gb space)
2. 2.one for root (min 6gb)
3. Last one for home.S (/home).

I recommend you to install kali Linux on VB - Visit
 [GOPCSOFT](http://www.gopcsoft.com/kali-linux-installation-on-virtual-box-step-by-step-guide/) that will guide to install Kali-Linux